# Implementing ScrollView Causes Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have a RelativeLayout which I'm attempting to add the ability to scroll down on - when the device is in the horizontal position. (Currently - a button disappears when you flip it horizontally - which is undesired.)

### Current XML State:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emblem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/emblem"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/start_text"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textSize="14sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

### The problem is when I attempt to change the XML above to a ScrollView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emblem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/emblem"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/start_text"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textSize="14sp" />



</ScrollView>
```

### I get a Fatal Exception:

```
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.new.datasettings/com.project.new.datasettings.StartActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1985)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:241)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:743)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:252)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1841)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at com.project.new.datasettings.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:44)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4471)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1924)
08-23 11:06:52.419: E/AndroidRuntime(3919):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You need to remove the `xmlns` tag for the RelativeLayout. There only needs to be one namespace(ns) per xml doc. I updated my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ScrollView` can only have one child element. You have 3, the Button, ImageView, and TextView. Try wrapping your `RelativeLayout` with a `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/go_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emblem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/emblem"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="@string/start_text"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:textSize="14sp" />



 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView can not add more than two views in it.... So it is better to use that in ScrollView you can take one LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and the add other Layout in it.. And finally add child views in it...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code as:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emblem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/text"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/emblem"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/start_text"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textSize="14sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```